# Android Programming Errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to develop Android apps via Java,Eclipse.

I'm trying to use this [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).

My activity:

```
package grid.View;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getVieww(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageVieww;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageVieww = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageVieww.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageVieww.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageVieww.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageVieww = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageVieww.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageVieww;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have this error for all those "samples":

> sample_2 cannot be resolved or is not a field

What I'm supposed to do? :S

Thanks!

Comment: What line is it pointing to? You may need to be more specific this because it could be numerous things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.drawable.sample_2` refers to a image called "sample_2" in your drawable folder.
If it shows this error, either the image isn't available in your drawable folder(s) (missing, different name?), or you haven't imported the `R.java` file.

By the looks of it, you haven't downloaded the images described in the example and put them in your `drawables` folder.

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to have images in your drawable folder, named `sample_0.png` to `sample_7.png`
The Android SDK will detect them and generate variables `R.drawable.sample_X` (X - 0 to 7) for you to use.

Comment: Yeah thanks, thats solved the problem. Now I can compile that, but the app crashes. (FORCE KILL BLAH BLAH BLAH..) :/

Comment: Post your logcat containing the exception stack trace in a new question, we may help

Answer (score 1):

This means that there is not such resource in your drawables folder. Either you have to add it there or don't use it anymore.

In case you actually have it, then try to clean & build again your project.

Hope this helps!